# Not getting current position when map is dragged

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, .net, google-maps

I want to get current position (latitude and longitude)  when map is dragged.

For that i am using following code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map  , 'drag', function(event) {
            addMarker(event.latLng.lat(), event.latLng.lng());
        });
```

But unfortunately, event does not contain latlang functions or properties in it.

event.constructor,event.hasownproperty...etc..

but there is not event.latLng.lat()

Comment: Check if u are added J query plug in path to u r aspx page.

Comment: no not added, i am not using jquery in this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where do you want to place the marker?

You can for example get the center of the map this way:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function() {
    alert(map.getCenter());
});
```

Here the [reference of the Map class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map)

Comment: man you have solved my problem...you are the greatest man on the earth...i was struggling since from morning, but just copy pasted ur answer and work done...god bless you...happy diwali!!!